# Include personal link to poster in Graduate School CV

Tags: citations, cv, research-undergraduate, poster

I am currently editing my CV for grad school applications with Latex. In my list of conference presentations (posters and an oral), I have provided hyperlinks to arXiv citations of my abstracts, but I don't have a citation hyperlink available for one poster presented at two (1 state & regional) conferences.

Would it be considered unnecessary or weird to an Admissions Committee to include a Google Drive, for instance, to the actual poster? I feel like including it so that the committee can actually look at my research projects if they desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, anything that can help folks access your works easier from your CV is a good thing.  I include links in mine for any articles that are in open-access journals or conference papers that are in public archives.  For the poster, though, make sure it's well proofread and up to date research, I think - I wouldn't go back and put all your posters online, maybe just your most recent ones?

Comment: Thanks for the response. All of my poster conferences are in 2016 and 2017, so is that considered recent enough? In regards to up-to-date, this poster was a small research project that I didn't plan to continue, but thought it would be good to highlight my work.